# Create Txt file from my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I need to create text file from my custom plugin. it's like create text file and adding some content, then email the file to admin.  i used fopen() function. It is giving me permission denied error.

```
fopen(/opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/includes/Frontend/errors.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin/includes/Frontend/Frontend.php on line 130
```

my code is:

```
    $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'errors.txt';
    $open = fopen($file, "a");
    $write = fputs($open, $response);
    fclose($open);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the plugin directory has `777` permissions, wordpress default folder permissions are `775`. You can change permission by running command if you have shell access:

```
sudo chmod 777 <path to you plugin dir>
```

Or if you have cpanel access, navigate using `File Manager` and right click the folder and select `Change Permissions` from the list.

Comment: Thank you for response, i am working in local, i run this command and changed the permission but still having same issue.  sudo chmod -c -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite  .

Comment: fopen() is the only way to create file in wordpress?

Comment: sudo chmod -c -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/wp-content/plugins/custom-plugin